# How to echo date to file via a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, echo

I am using a Makefile for my projects. I need my makefile to echo the date and my computer name to a file:

```
files:
    echo " *      Author: $(whoami)" >> myFile
    echo " *  Created on: $(date +%D)" >> myFile
```

I would assume an file looking like this:

```
*      Author: eDeviser
*  Created on: 02.01.2017
```

Nevertheless it looks like this:

```
*      Author:
*  Created on:
```

I tried to type the two lines directly into my terminal. This works very well:

```
$echo " *      Author: $(whoami)" >> myFile
$echo " *  Created on: $(date +%D)" >> myFile
$cat myfile
 *  Created on: 01/02/17
 *      Author: lukas
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`make` also uses the `$(` `)` syntax for its variables and functions.

Use `$$` to get a single `$` into the command you want to run:

```
files:
        echo " *      Author: $$(whoami)" >> myFile
        echo " *  Created on: $$(date +%D)" >> myFile
```